# Printing sales order doesnt work with exact online

Tags: python, exact-online

I am trying to print a sales order with a known OrderId however it throws an error which I haven't been able to debug.

```
printest = {
  "OrderId" : "0b28a174-524d-4fe3-b763-6b594d24afaa",
  "DocumentLayout" : "78aabba4-dbc5-416a-bb09-51aeca8dfd5d"
}

headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',  
        'Content-Type': '*/*',
        'Prefer': 'return=representation'
}

test = requests.post("https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/[division]/salesorder/PrintedSalesOrders",headers=headers, data=printest)
test.json()
```

error is:

```
{'error': {'code': '',
  'message': {'lang': '',
   'value': "Error reading syndication item: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'."}}}
```

What is the problem here? Please help

Comment: That url doesn't look quite right... `[division]` looks like it needs to be replaced by something.

Comment: I just omitted that part. I know the division code and i can make other api calls. It is just this one so far which has been problematic for me

Comment: Maybe it is wise to limit the number of platforms you ask the same question on to 1 per day.

Comment: Exact online ended up making a case and suggesting me to use postman instead as a solution. If that's what you mean by posting on multiple platforms!

Comment: That's an error you get if you try to read invalid XML data. But you're trying to use JSON. You have the right URL for the REST API and not the XML API, right? Perhaps `Content-Type` should be `application/json`? Just throwing that out there, I know nothing about that site or its API.

Comment: @RandomDavis  I tried Accept type as application/xml too and read the test variable as test.content but jt gives the same error. Tried content type as /json but the content i am sending is not in json as the server threw an error and told me to use application/json application/atom+xml or */* . Yes i believe i am using rest api. Such a weird error and the support team just adviced me to use postman.

Comment: Well if you use Postman you can compare the headers it's sending versus Python so that you can figure out what the issue is. Then once you do you can self-answer your question with the solution so that others can be helped in the future.

Comment: Tried with the postman and I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to use the json argument instead of using data.

This

```
requests.post("url",headers=headers, data=printest)
```

becomes

```
requests.post("url",headers=headers, json=printest)
```

`Content-Type` header can be set as `application/json`